# How do you setup a function in Moq for a generic function that returns T types?

Tags: moq

I have a mock DB object where the setup is a generic function, the first time it is called in the unit test, it returns one type, but the next time it is called, the type will change to another type.

I initially experimented with SetupSequence and making the return type object, but of course the moq never gets called because the types do not match:

```
mockdbobj.SetupSequence(x => x.GetData<Object>())
            .Returns(type1)
            .Returns(type2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading someone's post on how the setup is a builder object, I realized to make this work, I just need to call setup for each type:

```
mockdbobj.Setup(x => x.GetData<SomeTypeOne>())
            .Returns(type1);
mockdbobj.Setup(x => x.GetData<SomeTypeTwo>())
            .Returns(type2);
```